# JSON_value function not returning exact value

Tags: oracle, json-value

I was trying extract value in SQL developer from below json but it gives me wrong output

```
select
json_value('{"ABC": {
    "CFF": 90,
    "coord": {
      "x1": 27.4,
      "x2": 31.6,
      "y1": 61.4,
      "y2": 62.4
    },
    "value": "\\"
  }}','$."ABC".value') COL from dual
```

[image]

Kindly suggest ..

Answer (score 1):

The backslash symbol `\` is also an escape character - so `\\` in a quoted string `"\\"` becomes a single unescaped `\`

If you want the value to be `\\` you have to double the amount of backslashes to `\\\\`

Comment: Well data is coming from different system, We need to extract as it is.

Comment: In that case the different system has to double the amount of backslashes when inserting the data into the database. The value in the database is missing the `\` if it is unescaped

Comment: As Daniel said, the \ is defined by JSON standard (not Oracle) as an escape character, with \\ meaning just one \. If you insert the string there in a 19c database, with a column defined as varchar2, it will have "\\" in there, but when you apply json functions, the string will be parsed and what the JSON standard says applies.